# How did langid.py create the model binary as strings in code?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, nlp, binary

[Langid.py](https://github.com/saffsd/langid.py) is a popular language detection library.

Inside the library's [`langid.py` file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/saffsd/langid.py/master/langid/langid.py), there's a peculiar way that encodes the binary inside the Python code

```
model=b"""
QlpoOTFBWSZTWRcOrWEAUJJfgGAQAMN...
"""
```

And the model is loaded by `load_model()` function that calls `LanguageIdentifier.from_modelstring()`

```
def load_model(path = None):
  """
  Convenience method to set the global identifier using a model at a
  specified path.

  @param path to model
  """
  global identifier
  logger.info('initializing identifier')
  if path is None:
    identifier = LanguageIdentifier.from_modelstring(model)
  else:
    identifier = LanguageIdentifier.from_modelpath(path)

class LanguageIdentifier(object):
  """
  This class implements the actual language identifier.
  """

  @classmethod
  def from_modelstring(cls, string, *args, **kwargs):
    b = base64.b64decode(string)
    z = bz2.decompress(b)
    model = loads(z)
    nb_ptc, nb_pc, nb_classes, tk_nextmove, tk_output = model
    nb_numfeats = int(len(nb_ptc) / len(nb_pc))

    # reconstruct pc and ptc
    nb_pc = np.array(nb_pc)
    nb_ptc = np.array(nb_ptc).reshape(nb_numfeats, len(nb_pc))
```

How was the model's binary string created?

Are there other examples/library of saving/loading models and binaries in similar manner?

Comment: It will take some more sleuthing, but from my quick read this looks like it's computing a naive Bayes classification (see the dot product and argmax in `nb_classproduct` and `classify`, respectfully). Therefore the `model` is probably a base64 encoded numpy array. I cannot recall specific examples of libraries that do this, but this probably does take less space than including an array represented with text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort of reverse engineer the serialization process by simply looking at how they decode it.

It is apparent that the operations `b64decode` -> `decompress` -> `loads` are happening. Furthermore, the object that is pickle loaded clearly seems to be a list of lists, numpy arrays, or a mix of other python objects.

From this, if we arrange the operations in opposite, then maybe `dumps` -> `compress` and `b64encode` may have been used?

```
import numpy as np
from pickle import loads, dumps
import bz2
import base64

# I don't actually know what model contains, but they most definitely have
# at least two numpy arrays. Since they need to call np.array( ) around the 
# recovered objects, the arrays were also most likely converted to lists
# beforehand.

model = [
    np.random.randn(50).tolist(),
    np.random.randn(10).tolist(),
    np.random.randn(5).tolist(),
    100,
    ["hello", "world"]
]

def serialize(model):
    serialized_str = dumps(model)
    serialized_str = bz2.compress(serialized_str)
    serialized_str = base64.b64encode(serialized_str)
    return serialized_str

serialized_model = serialize(model)
print(serialized_model)
```

This creates something like:

```
b'QlpoOTFBWSZTWZOjK1MAAKt////f/+/3/9v+/v2b5/7//fl+/9fv/f3xbv//7//f/Pf/sAGZYmIygxNAAADQZ...
```

Let's try retrieving our stuff from this string with their function:

```
def from_modelstring(string):
    b = base64.b64decode(string)
    z = bz2.decompress(b)
    model = loads(z)
    nb_ptc, nb_pc, nb_classes, tk_nextmove, tk_output = model
    nb_numfeats = int(len(nb_ptc) / len(nb_pc))

    # reconstruct pc and ptc
    nb_pc = np.array(nb_pc)
    nb_ptc = np.array(nb_ptc).reshape(nb_numfeats, len(nb_pc))
    return [nb_ptc, nb_pc, nb_classes, tk_nextmove, tk_output]

retrieved_model = from_modelstring(serialized_model)
for stuff in retrieved_model:
    print(stuff)
```

This rolls out pretty much the stuff we serialized earlier (except they reshaped the first array).

```
[[ 1.05455975  1.47333935  1.37442491 -0.02935783 -0.24073724 -1.49982221
  -0.20562748  1.00599094 -0.39817881  2.38135877]
 [-2.26547287  0.40649275 -0.42671883 -0.14154335  0.16647036 -0.4369942
   0.56737926  0.84126397 -1.80242939 -0.46906909]
 [ 0.24276755  1.00126493  0.42857048 -2.27383095 -0.39111637  1.72592306
  -0.41461467  2.70302884  0.21227391 -1.53374656]
 [-0.3529697  -0.58519877  0.01826065 -0.27764779 -0.36591068  0.01622645
   1.13080176  2.06702545  0.97302083 -0.32730124]
 [ 0.74106848  0.41801277  1.10355551 -0.46584239  1.08019501 -0.30003819
  -0.22321621 -0.66239601  0.87712623 -0.97101542]]
[ 0.45764773 -1.2864595   0.63190841 -0.70456336 -1.47569178  0.71870362
  0.1655068  -0.80424568 -0.64359963  1.38405498]
[2.1449875114268377, 0.4234196905494024, -0.27539676193149465, 0.37630564468835975, -0.1623772359974499]
100
['hello', 'world']
```

I am not sure whether other libraries store models exactly in this manner, but quite a few (if not nearly all) of them definitely use pickle to binarize and dump their models. For example, pytorch uses a combination of pickling and zipping in [torch.save](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.save.html).

Comment: This is an awesome answer!! Thank you.